# How to learn the link between C++ code and the generated assembly code?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction, assembly

My question is specifically for Windows C++ compilers and Visual Studio, but I got offered to interview for a job in finance where they wanted somebody very technical to write real-time multi-threaded code who could analyse at assembly level the code generated by a C++ compiler.

What are the methods one can apply to learn the link between C++ code and the generated assembly and achieve this level of proficiency ?

Comment: 1. learn assembly, 2. learn some compiler theory, 3. inspect a lot of compiler output (try bit-fiddling algorithms).

Comment: Analyse it for what? Why would such code need to be multithreaded?  Why would it have to be real-time? Doesn't sound much like finance to me - finance keywords, (ie. the ones I try to avoid:), are normally 'SQL, Oracle, stored procedures, triggers'.

Comment: You can of course make your compiler generate assembly as output which you can inspect, but if you don't know assembly, that output will be pretty much meaningless. You have to learn assembly, something that is beyond the scope of a Q&A forum such as stackoverflow.

Comment: @Martin James, it is for automated high frequency trading, they seem to require one person to write the code which will execute the trades from the strategies or rewrite the code from the strategies ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to learn the assembler and machine code.
There is some very good documentation of the machine code available at
the Intel site (although it may be more detailed than you need). There
are two common assembler formats in widespread use: the one used by
Microsoft is based on the original Intel assembler, where as g++ uses
something completely different (based on the original Unix assembler for
PDP-11), so you'll have to choose one (although the assembler syntax
itself is rarely a real problem—knowing what the individual 
instructions do is more important).

Once you have some idea of how to read assembler: most compilers
have options to output assembler: for VC++, use `/Fa` (and `/c` as well,
if you don't want to actually link the results); for g++, `-S` (which
causes the compiler to stop once it has generated the assembler.  In the
case of VC++, the assembler will be in a file `xxx.asm` (where `xxx.cpp`
was the name of the file being compiled), for g++, `xxx.s`.  Try
compiling some code, with different levels of optimization, and then
look at the assembler in an editor.

Finally, if the question is asked, it's probably because the interviewer
is concerned about performance issues; what he's really interested in is
whether you know the relative cost of various operations (or the risks
involved when multithreading; e.g. what operations are atomic, etc.)  In
which case, it probably wouldn't hurt to point out that issues like
locality (which determines the percent of cache hits) are often more
important that the individual operations.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer to this is., To compile code and look at it in the debugger.

Debuggers will show you connection between the two in a very harsh way. The next step is to understand compiler theory and then look at the source code of compilers to understand what they try and do.

I think the person interviewing you may have been trying to see if you can understand what kind of effort is involved - rather than actually knowing how to do it.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, your is very concise and clear but I accepted the other one as it was more detailed for my needs